# Java extending classes

Tags: java, inheritance

BasePage.java

```
public class BasePage {
  //do stuff
}
```

Center.java

```
public class Center {
    public BasePage click(){
        click(button);
        return new BasePage(this);
    }

    // do other stuff
}

public class Helper {
    protected Center center;

        // do stuff
}
```

Page.java

```
public class Page extends BasePage {
   //do stuff
}
```

TestClass.java

```
public class TestClass extends Helper {
    private Page page;

    // I can use "center.click()" because TestClass extends from Helper, 
    // and "center" is a protected variable in Helper
    // "center.click()" returns type 'BasePage'
    // 'page' is a type 'Page' which extends 'BasePage'
    // So why can't I put the result of "center.click()" into 'page' ?
    page = center.click();

}
```

Comment: You cannot assign superclass reference to subclass reference.

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman: My question is in the comment section of the class TestClass.java why can't I assign center.click() to page?

Comment: It doesn't look like you understand inheritance correctly. Don't use inheritance EVERYWHERE. Use it [where it makes sense.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument)

Comment: @Maya because a BasePage is not always a Page, in the same way that an Object is not always a String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take this example:

```
Subclass inherits from Superclass

Subclass sub;

sub = new Superclass(); // is not valid

Superclass super = new Subclass(); // is valid
// basic laws of polymorphism
```

The easiest way to understand it is, the container should be bigger than the type of object it is storing. In this case, Superclass is bigger than Subclass, that's why the second statement is correct.

If you need to use the first statement by any means, try casting.

```
sub = (Subclass)(new Superclass()); // is valid
```

Answer (score 2):

```
page = center.click();
```

Your `page` is a reference of `baseclass Page` whereas your method `center.click()` returns an object of type super class `BasePage`.

You cannot assign assign a superclass object to sub class reference.

You will need to typecast explicitly your `BasePage` to `Page`: -

```
page = (Page)center.click();
```

**But that also may not work because**, you are returning `new BasePage(this)` from your method, which is not an instance of `Page`.

You need to return an object of type `Page` rather like: - `new Page(this)`, which you can typecast to assign to Page reference..

Also, you are doing this assignment inside the `class` directly which is not correct. Either you need to have a method, or you need to initialize it at the time of declaration only..

```
Page page = (Page)center.click();
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I suppose that somebody downvoted you because click() returns a "new BasePage(this)". That can't be casted to a Page (because it is not one).

Comment: @Pablo Ok. I didn't see that earlier. Modified my post accordingly. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Two problems. First, `page = center.click();` does not seem to be inside a method. (If it actually isn't in your code, fix that first.)

Then, the assignment still won't work because the `BasePage` that `center.click()` returns may not be an instance of `Page`. (In fact, it is not.)

Make the following substitutions to your code for `Center` and `TestClass`:

> `BasePage` => `Object`
>   `Page` => `String`

It should then be clear why there's a problem.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you cannot assign a superclass object to a subclass object. Assuming your code is correct, on your `Center.click()` method, you are returning a new `BasePage` object. `Page` is a subclass of `BasePage` and that assignment cannot work.

You will have to return a class that is either a `Page` or subclass of `Page` and then type-cast it to `Page`.